# Python Script Connecting To MySQL Database - Code ran as procedural script, fails after OOP refactor

Tags: python, mysql, oop, inheritance

I have a script that can run a number of different reports, based on what input it receives via the command line. All reports read from a database and return the results as a Pandas Dataframe object.

Here is the super-class, (omitting a large number of property getter and setter functions):

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as p
import config

class Report(object):

    _connection = None
    _cursor = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._user = config.user
        self._password = config.password
        self._host = config.host
        self._database = config.database
        self._port = config.port
        self._body_text = "Hello,\n\nPlease find attached these reports:\n\n"
        self._connection = mysql.connector.connect(user=self._user, password=self._password, db=self._database,
                                                   host=self._host, port=self._port)
        self._cursor = self._connection.cursor()

    @property
    def user(self):
        return self._user

    @user.setter
    def user(self, value):
        self._user = value


. . . 


    @property
    def body_text(self):
        return self._body_text

    @body_text.setter
    def body_text(self, value):
        self._body_text = value

    def append_body_text(self, value):
        self._body_text += value

    def get_data(self, server_cursor, query, columns):
        server_cursor.execute(self, query)
        results = server_cursor.fetchall()
        data = p.DataFrame(data=results, columns=[columns])
        return data

    def get_today(self):
        return self.today

    def close(self):
        self._connection_web.close()
        self._connection_raw.close()

    @staticmethod
    def insert_variables_into_sql_statement(query, external_data):
        final_query = query % external_data
        return final_query

    @staticmethod
    def create_string_from_column(serial):
        created_list = serial.tolist()
        string = ', '.join(map(str, created_list))
        return string

    @staticmethod
        def write_to_csv(data_frame, file_name):
        data_frame.to_csv(config.baseDirectory + file_name, sep=',', index=False)

    def generate_report(self):
        data = self.get_data(self._cursor_web, self._query, self._columns)
        self.write_to_csv(data, self._filename)
        self.close()
```

Here is how my subclasses are structured:

```
class ExampleReport(Report):
    def __init__(self):
        Report.__init__(self)
        self._query = """
        SELECT
        u.first_name AS 'First Name',
        u.last_name AS 'Last Name'
        FROM users AS u
        """
        self._columns = "'FirstName', 'LastName'"
        self._filename = "example_report.csv"
        self.append_body_text("* All users")
```

In my main method I call the method like this:

```
report = Reports.ExampleReport()
report.generate_report()
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ExampleReport' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

My database connections worked without a problem when it was terribly constructed procedural code (a working version is currently in production). It has broken now that I've tried to make it object oriented. Does anyone have any idea what I've done wrong?

**EDIT: SOLVED MY OWN PROBLEM!** In the `get_data` function in the super-class, the second line contained an erroneous `self` argument passed into `server_cursor.execute(query)` line. Once it was taken out, the error goes away.

Comment: Is `self.query` still a string when it gets passed to `get_data`?  ...for that matter, what's e.g. `_cursor_web` ?

Comment: Yes, self.query is still a string when it gets passed to get_data. What should it be if not a string?

_cursor_web is me failing to simplify some variable names for posting online. Its supposed to just be self._cursor

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED MY OWN PROBLEM! In the get_data function in the super-class, the second line contained an erroneous self argument passed into server_cursor.execute(query) line. Once it was taken out, the error goes away.